# Глюк IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от периодически появляющихся белых полос в  IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate? 
Дрова на видюху переустанавливал, не помогло.
Полосы появляются внезапно закрашивая всё до места установки курсора. Пока избавляюсь от них перезапуском идеи.
[image: ,tkfz gjkjcf 2]
[image: белая полоса]

Comment: Скорее-всего проблема не в IDE. Проблема может быть в железе ноутбука.

Comment: Больше похоже на баг в IntelliJ.